# Clojure + игровой движок со своим SDK, реально ли?

Tags: clojure, разработка-игр, sdk

Скажите пожалуйста, можно ли использовать Clojure в качестве скриптового языка для написания логики игры,в каком нибудь игровом движке где есть хороший SDK? Например для Unity3d нашел интересный проект, но не знаю насколько работоспособно:

[clojure-unity](https://github.com/clojure-unity/clojure-unity)

[как это выглядит](http://f.cl.ly/items/2T2d340o0k0W2d44212G/clj2.gif)